# try: except: not working

Tags: python, exception

So I'm running into a problem where the try: except: mechanism doesn't seem to be working correctly in python.

Here are the contents of my two files.

### pytest1.py

```
import pytest2

class MyError( Exception ):
    def __init__( self, value ):
        self.value = value

    def __str__( self ):
        return repr( self.value )

def func1():
    raise MyError( 'This is an error' )

def func3():
    pytest2.func2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        func3()
    except MyError, e:
        print 'I should catch here.'
    except:
        print 'Why caught here?'
```

### pytest2.py

```
from pytest1 import func1

def func2():
    func1()
```

Executing the first file yields the following output:

```
$ python pytest1.py
Why caught here?
```

Basically, the exception isn't being caught.  If I print out the exception type, it prints as `<pytest1.MyError>` instead of just `<MyError>`.  I imagine that this is some weird cyclical reference thing, but it still seems like it should work.

Comment: Winston's solution explains the problem, you can get your code to work correctly by adding the line `from pytest1 import *` to the beginning of the main code block (`if __name__ == '__main__':`) in pytest1.py, this will change `MyError` in the namespace from `<class '__main__.MyError'>` to `<class 'pytest1.MyError'>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main python program is always imported as the module `__main__`.

When you import `pytest2`, it doesn't reuse the existing module because the originally imported module has the name `__main__` not `pytest2`. The result is that `pytest1` is run multiple times generating multiple exception classes. `__main__.MyError` and `pytest1.MyError` You end up throwing one and trying to catch the other.

So, don't try to import your main module from other modules.

Comment: Confirmed.  Changing `pytest2` to `import __main__` and call `__main__.func1` makes the program behave as expected.  (For some reason, `from __main__ import func1` claims that there is no `func1` to import.)

Comment: Your second form won't work because in that case pytest2 is in the middle of being imported. It hasn't yet defined func1.

Comment: Make those modules contain library code only and have a central main entry point that imports all necessary parts from the modules without specifying anything itself.

Comment: Also confirmed, I ended up just creating another file to define functions and errors, and a separate file for command line.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by importing the script you are running as a module. This produces two separate copies of the module!

Another example:

**module.py**

```
import module

class Foo: pass

def test():
    print Foo
    print module.Foo
    print Foo is module.Foo

if __name__ == '__main__': test()
```

**main_script.py**

```
import module
if __name__ == '__main__': module.test()
```

**Result**

```
>python main_script.py
module.Foo
module.Foo
True

>python module.py
__main__.Foo
module.Foo
False
```

Running `python somefile.py` creates a module called `__main__`, *not* `somefile`, and runs the code in `somefile.py` in that module. This is why `if __name__ == '__main__':` is used to check if this file is being run as a script or imported from some other file.

Answer (score 1):

... at a guess, you have a namespace problem which is producing a different exception.

Try replacing

```
except:
    print 'Why caught here?'
```

with

```
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

This may tell you more about what went wrong.