# How can I catch an exception thrown in a function that I'm calling dynamically?

Tags: python-3.x

I got distracted and ended up writing a test framework in python. I'm struggling with a particular problem that this throws up.

During my assertion, I want to throw an exception as a way of bubbling a problem up to the run_test() method without requiring the user to have any knowledge of the framework. The problem is that when I do that, it seems that the try/catch block is not honoured.

Here is a cut down version of my fledgling framework:

```
# test_framework.py
import inspect
import module_containing_tests

class AssertionException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

def run_test(test_name, test_method):
    try:
        print(">", test_name)
        test_method()
        print("Passed")
    except AssertionException as error:
        print("Failed")
        print(str(error))

def assert_true(conditional):
    if not conditional:
        raise AssertionException("Expected True. Was False")

def test(func):
    func.is_test = True
    return func

members = inspect.getmembers(module_containing_tests)
for member in members:
    if "is_test" in dir(member[1]) and not member[0] == "module_containing_tests":
        run_test(member[0], member[1])
```

The module containing the tests will look like this:

```
# module_containing_tests.py
from test_framework import *

@test
def passing_test():
    assert_true(1 + 2 == 3)

@test
def failing_test():
    assert_true(1 + 2 == 5)
```

The output has all the exception stack tracing in it and it also halts the execution

```
λ python test_framework.py
> failing_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_framework.py", line 29, in <module>
    run_test(member[0], member[1])
  File "test_framework.py", line 13, in run_test
    test_method()
  File "C:\Git\simpy-test\module_containing_tests.py", line 9, in failing_test
    assert_true(1 + 2 == 5)
  File "C:\Git\simpy-test\test_framework.py", line 20, in assert_true
    raise AssertionException("Expected True. Was False")
test_framework.AssertionException: Expected True. Was False
```

What I want is something like this:

```
λ python test_framework.py
> failing_test
Expected True. Was False
Failed
> passing_test
Passed
```

Comment: But test method is invoked within a try/catch block. Surely any unhandled exceptions within that block will be caught by it?

Comment: Previous comment in response to a deleted comment ^^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is partly in the circular reference between the two files that might mess up with the visibility of the methods (as somehow explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952134/try-except-not-working)) and partly, maybe, in the approach. If you think about how many other testing framework work, you often have 3 elements, the unit to test, the testing framework and a test runner.

So if we try to split everythig folllowing that logic you end up having:

**test_framework.py**

```
# test_framework.py
class AssertionException(Exception):
    pass


def test(f):
   f.is_test = True
   return f


def assert_true(conditional):
    if not conditional:
        raise AssertionException("Expected True. Was False")
```

**test_runner.py**

```
# test_runner.py
import inspect

import unit_test
from test_framework import AssertionException


def run_test(test_name, test_method):
    try:
        print(">", test_name)
        test_method()
        print("Passed")
    except AssertionException as error:
        print("Failed with AssertionException: " + str(error))
    except Exception as error:
        print("Failed with Exception: " + str(error))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    members = inspect.getmembers(unit_test)
    for member in members:
        if "is_test" in dir(member[1]):
            run_test(member[0], member[1])
```

**unit_test.py**

```
# unit_test.py
from test_framework import *


@test
def a_passing_test():
    assert_true(1 + 2 == 3)


@test
def z_failing_test():
    assert_true(1 + 2 == 5)
```

With this setup the circular dependency is removed and all the visibility context are respected and the output/behaviour is the expected one.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you want but this works.
Copied from here [Hide traceback unless a debug flag is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674602/hide-traceback-unless-a-debug-flag-is-set)

Output:

```
$ ./test_framework.py
> a_passing_test
Passed
> z_failing_test
test_framework.AssertionException: Expected True. Was False
```

First file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#test_framework.py

import inspect 
import module_containing_tests 
import sys


class AssertionException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

def run_test(test_name, test_method):
    try:
        print(">", test_name)
        test_method()
        print("Passed")
    except AssertionException as error:
        print("Failed")
        print(str(error))

def assert_true(conditional):
    if not conditional:
        raise AssertionException("Expected True. Was False")

def test(func):
    func.is_test = True
    return func


sys.tracebacklimit=0
members = inspect.getmembers(module_containing_tests)
for member in members:
    if "is_test" in dir(member[1]) and not member[0] == "module_containing_tests":
        run_test(member[0], member[1])
```

second file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#module_containing_tests.py
from test_framework import *

@test
def a_passing_test():
    assert_true(1 + 2 == 3)

@test
def z_failing_test():
    assert_true(1 + 2 == 5)
```